# How to enumerate all strictly increasing smooth functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(t)$ be a strictly increasing function which maps the line segment onto itself $[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$.

How would one enumerate all such functions? For example, one could find the Fourier decomposition, but then how would one restrict the decomposition so that it only creates strictly increasing functions?

In other words I would like to express $f$ in terms of an infinite series of orthogonal functions, say, so that it can be represented as an infinite series.

This would be useful, for example, if one were to do a functional integral $\int D[f]$ over the space of strictly increasing functions $f$.

Comment: There are uncountably many such.

Comment: @lulu True, but mathematicians are comfortable talking about varying sizes of infinity.

Comment: You can't enumerate the elements of an uncountable set.  By definition.  And "smooth" is a weak property, really.  Your function might be linear from $[0,t]$ and non-linear after.

Comment: @zooby typically to enumerate means to put them into a bijection with a countable set.

Comment: OK, I'm using a more loose definition in terms of a bijection with an uncountable set

Comment: @zooby Can you please tell us what you want to do with this information? You mentioned integration of a functional over the space of functions - do you in fact want to check if there is a good **measure** one can define on some $\sigma$-algebra over the set of all monotonically increasing functions? Isn't that one of those things that physicists call "path integral"? In that case, "enumerate" is the wrong word, this is not a set-theoretical question.

Comment: The set of derivatives of such functions contains all smooth positive functions.